# Как получить содержимое страницы на PHP закодированной с использованием content encoding br(алгоритм Brotli)?

Tags: php, compression, brotli

Напарсили страниц некоторого сайта, сейчас их содержимое в файлах. Оказалось что данные на сайте в определённый момент начали сжимать по алгоритму, который в заголовках ответа сервера обозначается Content-Encoding: br

В Интернете есть примеры как получать расшифрованное содержание страниц с использованием Curl, в данном же случаи сжатое содержание страниц уже получено и повторно парсить не желательно, так как процедура на день или более.

Поэтому вопрос какой функцией на PHP или если её нет то каким алгоритмом можно получить разархивированное содержание уже закопированных страниц, которые сжаты алгоритмом br?

Comment: Можете использовать функции расширения [php-ext-brotli](https://github.com/kjdev/php-ext-brotli)

Comment: Как раз сейчас думал его посмотреть. Скажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понимаю что стандартного функционала для декомпрессии по алгоритму brotli(как например в случаи с gzip) в php нет? Или может быть для CentOs есть что либо устанавливаемое через yum install?

Comment: Для публичного использования в стандартных библиотеках нет, в CURL скорее всего есть, но опять же для внутреннего использования. Насчет YUM не знаю, создавайте новый вопрос для этого.